# Naming convention for service method

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

This is a basic naming convention question, but I didn't find anywhere that dealt with this specifically.

I have a class called Foo, and a class called Bar.

I have a method in a service to retrieve all of the Bars for a Foo.  Should I name it:

```
GetFooBars(int fooId)
```

or

```
GetBarsForFoo(int fooId)
```

To expand, you could have Bars for other classes, e.g.

```
GetMooBars(int mooId)
```

or

```
GetBarsForMoo(int mooId)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest

```
GetBarsByFooId(int fooId)

GetBarsByMooId(int mooId)
```

*Or*... tweaking your API to support a call like this

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(GetBarsByFooIdRequest))]
[KnownType(typeof(GetBarsByMooIdRequest))]
abstract class GetBarsRequest
{
   ..
}

[DataContract]
sealed class GetBarsByFooIdRequest : GetBarsRequest
{
   [DataMember]
   public int FooID { get; set; }
}

sealed class GetBarsByMooIdRequest : GetBarsRequest
{
   [DataMember]
   public int MooID { get; set; }
}

GetBarsResponse GetBars(GetBarsRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that you specified "...FooId".  My only caveat I have is that when I see "By", rather than "For", it makes me think that I am getting lots of (all?) Bars that are broken down by, or sorted by FooId (or MooId).  Alternatively, when I see "For", it makes me think I'm getting a subset of all Bars for just a particular FooId (or MooId).

Comment: When I see a name like `GetBarsByFooId`, it makes me think "filter by" or "search by". It had never occurred to me that it might mean "group by" or "order by". But that's just me... I guess the fact that you're passing `fooId` as a parameter should clarify the intent.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use one of the following:

```
GetBarsByFoo(int fooID) { }

GetBarsByMoo(int mooID) { }

GetBarsByFooId(int fooID){ }

GetBarsByMooId(int mooID){ }
```

Comment: `GetBarsByMooId` is repeated. I think you mean `GetBarsByMoo`.